# What are some ways to extract tables without any grid from pdf files in python?

Tags: python, opencv, tabula

I'm working on a project which requires me to automate the task of data extraction from tables in a pdf file. I'm using python for this project.

I'm wondering if there is any better way to approach this problem.

I have already used tabula however if the table doesn't have clear grids, tabula doesn't function properly.

I'm thinking of using Open CV to draw grids around the tables and cells then use OCR to extract the data from the files.

[Here is an example of a pdf page that I'm trying to extract the tables from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9am.png)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9am.png">
```

Comment: Ideally you would provide either an executable minimal example that illustrates your attempts and problems or provide at least some sample data. Otherwise it is rather hard to give you tipps.

Comment: You direction is correct. Opencv houghline for finding position. and OCR to find text. Just execute it. Shouldn`t have much issue.

Comment: @Snowbunting Thanks for your feedback and please accept my apology as it is my first question and I wasn't sure what to include. I have attached a picture to the question and I hope it helps.

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai Thank you. I will execute it and share updates of the project.

Answer (score 3):

As I noticed you deal with digital PDFs (not scanned ones). If you still would like to explore some possibilities of solving your problem without using OCR here you are:

- [Camelot - tabular data extractor](https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot). This library is good for working with "bad" tables without clear grids.
- You may also consider converting your PDF to text with [pdftotext](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/)
  and then parse it with Python.

Comment: Thanks, Nataliya. I have tried Camelot but unfortunately, it was unsuccessful and PDF to text works however it requires a lot of customization for each unique pdf file.